# Why are my input values being rounded down?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a decimal input valid however each time the decimal input gets rounded down. For example:  When I input 1.5 the program will round down to 1 or if I input 5.5 it rounds down to 5. How can I make it so when I enter an input with a decimal place it calculates that exact input?

```
weight = int(float(input('What is the weight of your package?: ')))
#Shipping Costs
flat_rate = float(20.00)
if weight <= 2:
  price_per_pound = float(1.50)
  price = float(weight * price_per_pound + flat_rate)
  print(price)
if weight > 2 and weight <= 6:
  price_per_pound = float(3.00)
  price = float(weight * price_per_pound + flat_rate)
  print(price)
else:
print('invalid entry')
```

Comment: You are converting float to int which by default will round down the number, to fix this change the first line to: ```weight = float(input('What is the weight of your package?: '))```

Comment: A lot of your usages of `float` For constants is unnecessary. Python doesn’t require you to declare variable types. However, if you want to keep track, you can use type hinting. Example - `flat_rate: float = 20.00`

Comment: It's converting to an integer because you told it to. `weight = int(...)` If you didn't want an integer, why are you using `int()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you storing a float in an int?
Change:

```
weight = int(float(input('What is the weight of your package?: ')))
```

to

```
weight = float(input('What is the weight of your package?: '))
```

Comment: I am a still learning python.  I thought the value entered would be a string and would have to be converted to an integer.  I understand why it was causing an issue now.  Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help!